# How to write selenium test function accurately with python pytest

Tags: python, selenium, pytest

I am new at selenium webdriver, python, pytest. I need suggestion how I can write a test function criteria with full of information and suggest me to the best way for writing test case. Please provide professional way to write a function.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I think first you have to decide if one single session is controlled by a single or multiple functions or whether you want multiple instances or not.

When it comes to selenium, you initiate a browser, control it, then close it.
If you fail to do it in this order, you end up with a tonne of chrome.exe instances in taskman.

Best testcase is initiating a browser, opening google, typing a word, hitting search and then saving the contents of the page to a variable.

If your intention is web scraping, definitely get yourself a copy of

> BeautifulSoup (pip install bs4)
> from bs4 import BeautfulSoup as bs